# Jquery UI Tabbed dialog close button not appearing on second and third click

Tags: html, jquery-plugins, jquery-ui-dialog, jquery-ui-tabs

I created two jquery UI dialogs wich has tabbed content inside it.Each tab has some forms,html ect.Also I want to reset the form values on closing.I wrote function in the close event and its almost working.

My problem is, When I close one dialog and ,try to open other dialog(without refreshinhg the page) the close button is missing.But when try to open and close the same dialog the close button is there and it works properly.

My HTML :

```
<!-----first tabbed dialog--->
        <div id="tenant" style="display:none;">
            <ul class="menu-ul">
                <li><a href="#evnt" title="one" onClick="etcGroupPopulate();">1</a></li>
                <li><a href="#event_type" title="two" onClick="etcCategoryPopulate();">2</a></li>
                <li><a href="#event_locations" title="three">3</a></li>
                <li><a href="#event_duration" title="four">4</a></li>
                <li><a href="#event_repeat" title="five" onClick="etcRecurrencePopulate();">5</a></li>
                <li class="ui-tab-dialog-close"></li>
            </ul>
    <div>
    <div id="evnt"></div>
    <div id="event_type"></div>
    <div id="event_location"></div>
    <div id="event_repeat"></div>
    </div>
    </div>
<!----second tabbed dialog---->

<div id="creatEvent" style="display:none;">
    <ul class="menu-ul">
        <li><a href="#event1" title="one"><label id="heading">Event</a></li>
        <li><a href="#event_occurence" title="two">Recurrence</a></li>
        <li class="ui-tab-dialog-close"></li>
    </ul>
    <div>

      <div id="event1"></div>
        <div id="event_occurence"></div>
        <div id="event_location"></div>
        <div id="event_repeat"></div>
        </div>
        </div>
```

My Jquery:

```
$('#rem_wizard').click(function(){
        tabpopup();
        $('#tenant').tabbedDialog();
    });
    $('#create_event').click(function(){ 
        tabpopup();
        $('#creatEvent').tabbedDialog();
    });

function tabpopup()
{
    $.fn.tabbedDialog = function () {
        this.tabs();
        this.dialog({
            'modal':true,
            'minWidth':700,

            modal: true,
            resizable: true,
            closeOnEscape: false,
            'minHeight':500,
            'draggable':true,
            close: clear
        });
        this.find('.ui-tab-dialog-close').append($('a.ui-dialog-titlebar-close'));
        this.find('.ui-tab-dialog-close').css({
            'position':'absolute',
            'right':'0', 
            'top':'23px'
        });
        this.find('.ui-tab-dialog-close > a').css({
            'float':'none',
            'padding':'0'
        });
        var tabul = this.find('ul:first');
        this.parent().addClass('ui-tabs').prepend(tabul).draggable('option','handle',tabul); 
        this.siblings('.ui-dialog-titlebar').remove();
        $('.next, .prev').on('click', function() {

            var x= $(this).attr('title');
            $("a[title='"+x+"']").trigger("click");

        }); 
    }
}


function clear() {

    $("#event1").closest('form').find("input[type=reset]").trigger("click");
    $("#payment, #payment1, .event_ends").hide();
    $("#event_locations").closest('form').find("input[type=reset]").trigger("click");
    $("#one").closest('form').find("input[type=reset]").trigger("click");
    $("#event_type").closest('form').find("input[type=reset]").trigger("click");


}
```